# WP_Query only returning one WooCommerce product

Tags: woocommerce, custom-post-type, wordpress

I'm trying to loop through all WooCommerce products in a particular category.

It should be as simple as:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'terms' => (int)$cat->term_id,
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    ))
);

$product_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($product_query->have_posts()) {
    echo '<p>';

    while($product_query->have_posts()) {
        $product_query->the_post();
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
    }

    echo '</p>';

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

However it only returns 1 product when I have 3 products in the category. If I echo `$product_query->found_posts` it says 3. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do the other 2 products have stock quantities?

Comment: @flauntster all products have stock management disabled and are showing as `in stock`

Comment: As Brett answered, your `$args` have `posts_per_page` value in the `tax_query`. Move it above it, and you'll be fine.

Comment: @dingo_d yeah I answered my own question... :)

Comment: I didn't notice that it was you xD Well glad you noticed :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Facepalm]

It took me 30 minutes of debugging the WordPress core to realise that the `posts_per_page` parameter goes in `$args['posts_per_page']` not in `$args['tax_query'][0]['posts_per_page']`